# how to consume php web service in c# Desktop application

Tags: c#, desktop-application

how to consume php web service in c# Desktop application. I am doing this by adding web reference and through code

```
WebReference.TestWSDL pdl = new testingApp.WebReference.TestWSDL();
```

string copy = pdl.verify("testing");

but it throws the error

**Possible SOAP version mismatch: Envelope namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ was unexpected. Expecting http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are sending the the appropriate soap version request that the service is expecting ie sending a soap 1.2 request to a service expecting a 1.1 request would give a similar error. Maybe run fiddler and post the messages that are sent and recieved for people to have a look at?